# Sql Server 2008 Missing Index on TempTable

Tags: sql-server-2008, query-optimization

I have developed a stored procedure with below code , by using the  **#tmpRIStatusReport**  as temp table and inserting the values into **#tmpRIStatusReport**  and for multi usage purpose.

while I was running the execution plan, It is saying the below message as missing the index on **#tmpRIStatusReport**.

```
/*
Missing Index Details from ~vs4E6E.sql - databaserver.databasename (developerID (113))
The Query Processor estimates that implementing the following index could improve the query cost by 18.9401%.
*/

/*
USE [tempdb]
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [<Name of Missing Index, sysname,>]
ON [dbo].[#tmpRIStatusReport__________________________________________________________________________________________________00000000291F] ([SubId])

GO
*/
```

Please could you any one suggest me what I need to do?

Comment: You can create an index on your temp table in the stored procedure. You have to show your code for someone to suggest the appropriate index. It might be what is suggested by the execution plan and there might be better alternatives.

Comment: @Mikael, Please find the updated post for the whole SP code.

Comment: There is no `#tmpStatusReport` in your code. Would that be the same as `#tmpRIStatusReport`?

Comment: Yes Sir, that is #tmpRIStatusreport temp table.

Comment: That was a whole lot of code :). You could try the suggestion from the execution plan by adding `create index IX_tmpRIStatusReport_SubId on #tmpRIStatusReport(SubId)` right after the line where you do `SELECT ... INTO #tmpRIStatusReport ... ORDER BY ...`. Test it and see if it makes a difference in performance or not.